# Creating static methods that only the abstract class can access in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, abstract

ok, I have a weird one for you guys.  So we have:

```
class Animal {
    static PublicMethod() {
        console.log('I am abstract!');

        this.OnlyForAnimal(); // Good, Animal is allowed!
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    static OnlyForAnimal() { // Currently accessible by anyone.
        console.log('Only the Animal class should be able to use this function...');
    }
}


Dog.OnlyForAnimal(); // No, no one should be allowed to do this!
```

So, is it possible to make a static method only usable by the abstract class or to throw an error if someone other then the abstract class calls the method?  Can we in the Dog class output the name or object of the abstract class?

Comment: You want to declare a static method in `Dog` that only `Animal` can use? Not `Dog`?

Comment: Yes, a static method in Dog that only Animal can call.  Weird direction I know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it sounds like you want to declare a static method in `Dog` that only `Animal` can use.

You can't do that without having `Animal` set it up in some way. You have a couple of options:

- Slight obscurity via Symbol, or
- Privacy via `WeakMap`

*(It's tempting to think we could apply one of the new private class features to this ([fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), or [static private methods](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features/), etc.), but doing so would probably only be more complicated than the `WeakMap` without really offering anything, and you'd have to create a subclass of `Dog` when registering it. So I haven't done that here.)*

### Slight Obscurity

If *slight obscurity* rather than actual privacy is good enough, you could have `Animal` create a Symbol and add a method to `Dog` using that `Symbol`:

```
const Animal = (() => {
    const hidden = Symbol.for("Animal_hidden_static_method");
    // Or: `const hidden = Symbol();` if you don't need to worry about
    // cross-window issues

    return class Animal {
        static PublicFunction() {
            console.log('I am abstract!');
        }

        static registerClass(cls) {
            cls[hidden] = function() {
                // `Animal` can easily call this method; others have
                // to work harder to do do it
            };
        }

        static useTheMethod(cls) {
            cls[hidden](); // <== Calls the method with `this` set to the class constructor
        }
    };
})();

class Dog extends Animal {
}
Animal.registerClass(Dog);

// ...
Animal.useTheMethod(Dog);
```

Again, though, that's just slight obscurity, not privacy. Anything can use `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` on `Dog` to find the symbol that names the method.

### Actual Privacy

If you need actual privacy, you can do it by not putting the method on `Dog` at all, but creating a function you associate with `Dog` via a `WeakMap` that only `Animal` has access to:

```
const Animal = (() => {
    const methods = new WeakMap();

    return class Animal {
        static PublicFunction() {
            console.log('I am abstract!');
        }

        static registerClass(cls) {
            methods.set(cls, function() {
                // Only `Animal` can call this function. The function is garbage-collectable
                // when the class used as a the key is garbage-collectable
            });
        }

        static useTheMethod(cls) {
            const method = methods.get(cls);
            method.call(cls); // <== Calls the method with `this` set to the class constructor
        }
    };
})();

class Dog extends Animal {
}
Animal.registerClass(Dog);
```

Comment: Interesting.  ok, I copied the code and I got this error message: Uncaught TypeError: Animal.register is not a function

Comment: @MightyMouse - I kinda called it `register` in one place but `RegisterClass` in another. :-D I've called it `registerClass` everywhere now.

Comment: Thank you.  Did not think that was possible using that method.  Cheers.